# Error starting domain with startWebLogic

Tags: oracle, service, weblogic, soa, osb

I installed the following distributions and followed the accompanying install instructions:

fmw_12.2.1.1.0_infrastructure.jar

fmw_12.2.1.1.0_soa.jar

fmw_12.2.1.1.0_osb.jar

However, when starting the weblogic server (...//Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh), these exceptions occur without any applications deployed...

Not really sure where to go to find the solution for this... Can someone please provide some help...

Thanks in advance...

LOG:

```
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:42,69 PM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170032> <The Server has detected ODL configuration for java.util.logging. The PlatformLoggerLevels attribute configuration on the LogMBean will be ignored.>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,942 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n-schemas.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n-schemas.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n-schemas.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,951 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,954 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,956 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jakarta-oro.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jakarta-oro.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jakarta-oro.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,958 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/wlw-system.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/wlw-system.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-10-21T11:12:26.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/wlw-system.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,960 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_common.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_common.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_common.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,982 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/struts.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/struts.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:30:44.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/struts.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:50,995 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-digester.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-digester.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-digester.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,8 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/com.bea.core.process_5.4.0.0.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/com.bea.core.process_5.4.0.0.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/com.bea.core.process_5.4.0.0.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,12 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,16 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2015-08-29T04:42:58.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,18 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-07-28T15:21:04.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,19 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jstl.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jstl.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/jstl.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,22 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_system.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_system.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_system.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,24 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_system.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_system.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/netuix_system.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,39 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_common.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_common.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-04-21T14:27:16.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_common.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,157 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2015-08-30T07:30:58.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,159 PM CDT> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:.../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar ,md5sum:<failed to calculate due to IOException>java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar (Too many open files), lastModified:2014-07-28T15:21:04.000-0500.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,248 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149605> <Failed to create App/Comp MBeans for AppDeploymentMBean weblogic. Error - weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files).
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(WarDeploymentFactory.java:81)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:131)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:94)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.existsInWar(WarUtils.java:160)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,314 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "consoleapp" due to error weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/META-INF/application.xml (Too many open files)
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/META-INF/application.xml (Too many open files)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DescriptorParsingFlow.parseDDs(DescriptorParsingFlow.java:157)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DescriptorParsingFlow.prepare(DescriptorParsingFlow.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:731)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:243)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/META-INF/application.xml (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at weblogic.utils.jars.BaseExplodedJarFile.getInputStream(BaseExplodedJarFile.java:53)
        at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getInputStream(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:399)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:51,323 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "weblogic" due to error weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files)
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(WarDeploymentFactory.java:81)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:131)
        at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:94)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Test/OSB12/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/osb_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.internal/weblogic.war (Too many open files)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.existsInWar(WarUtils.java:160)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:52,740 PM CDT> <Critical> <JTA> <BEA-110482> <A logging last resource (LLR) failed during initialization. The server cannot boot unless all configured LLRs initialize. Failing reason:
weblogic.common.ResourceException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'SOADataSource'.

weblogic.common.ResourceException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'SOADataSource'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:401)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:52,766 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "SOADataSource" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'SOADataSource'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'SOADataSource'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:411)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'SOADataSource'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:322)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.loadDriver(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:70)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.<init>(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:116)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:1227)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:226)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 19, 2016, 1:28:55,158 PM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "wlsbjmsrpDataSource" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'wlsbjmsrpDataSource'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'wlsbjmsrpDataSource'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:411)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl for datasource 'wlsbjmsrpDataSource'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:322)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.loadDriver(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:70)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.<init>(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:116)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:1227)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:226)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS limit of open files is too low to successfully start SOA domain, to check current value, simply run "ulimit -n" command.

To fix the issue, run* from root user:

```
echo "oracle soft nofile 65536" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "oracle hard nofile 65536" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

*replace oracle with user that is used to run WebLogic domain.

You will need to logout/login for the changes to take effect.

Changing this value is one of required prerequisites mentioned in Oracle documentation [Oracle® Fusion Middleware System Requirements and Specifications 12c (12.2.1.1.0)](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E73100_01/toc.htm). I would suggest checking if other prerequisites are met to avoid further problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: Thanks for answering. That solved the error. But now I have a new one

Answer (score 0):

oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl requires installation of the Oracle 12.2 database driver jar files.
Since the Oracle 12.2 hasn't shipped yet, this isn't documented.
It was added early for customers running with the Oracle 12.2 Beta.
Also, it's likely when it does ship that initially the only product certified will be WebLogic Server.